# Install Python Module pyodbc on PI?

Tags: raspbian, python, pi-2, mysql

I am trying to connect to a MS SQL database and get some values over a Raspberry Pi. I have my Python script and it works well on windows, but i dont know how to install the 'pyodbc' module on the PI.

Does the 'pyodbc' work on the PI?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: try pip install pyodbc (you may need to use sudo to install successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever possible use apt-get to install packages on Raspbian.

You can then be sure the package will be consistent with the rest of the installed packages.

Search for candidates as follows

```
$ apt-cache search odbc | grep python

python-egenix-mxdatetime - date and time handling routines for Python
python-pyodbc - Python module for ODBC database access
python-pyodbc-dbg - Python module for ODBC database access - Debugging symbols
```

Install as follows (say y at the prompt to install)

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-pyodbc

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libodbc1
Suggested packages:
  libmyodbc odbc-postgresql tdsodbc unixodbc-bin
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libodbc1 python-pyodbc
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 225 kB of archives.
After this operation, 610 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Answer (score 0):

PI to SQL Server works as of 7/29/2018. I am much better at MS SQL than Raspbian or Linux and the Pi, but it does work.  Setting it up requires a little documentation from everywhere.  Python 2 and Python 3 are both installed on the Pi for the newest Raspbian OS.  You must be sure pyodbc is installed on Python 3 and the driver is setup and configured.   If not, the first statement --> import pyodbc will fail.

Ok here is a good head start there are several components you will need.

https://tryolabs.com/blog/2012/06/25/connecting-sql-server-database-python-under-ubuntu/
is a great place to start.

After you go through their docs.
A note about /etc/odbcinst.ini file.
Below is a command to edit it easily.

sudo nano /etc/odbcinst.ini

Your drivers will located a different place for the PI in the odbcinst.ini file.

These were double checked this is where mine were installed.
Driver = /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup = /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/odbc/libtdsS.so
Fix this.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33446347/no-module-named-pymysql

This helped me get mine working.

Last minute change to get python 3 working and the next held me up a while
sudo apt-get install python3-pymysql

This last command fixed me.
sudo dpkg-reconfigure tdsodbc

These commands might help
pip3 list
pip list

After all this is done, hopefully you will be closer to yours working after this.  I have it working with Python 2 and 3 and Tkinter.    I also have it working on Windows IoT Core on the Pi.  My little video shows the speed and that yes it can work very well, I just had to show it.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IheBtUG1PFM

Again this is not the best way to access the database unless you have complete control of the network.  You should use a Rest or Web Services process across the web.  It is much more secure.

I will try and put all this together in a document when I can find time to try it from a fresh Pi Raspbian build.